# Amcharts4: How to add an image to an axis (valueAxis) label?

Tags: image, axis, amcharts, axis-labels, amcharts4

With amcharts4, I would like to add an image to a ValueAxis's label. Is this possible? I've found out, how to add an SVG image to a bullet (see [demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/column-chart-images-top/)). But is it possible to do something similar with the label of the ValueAxis?

Here is an example of such an image, I would like to add next to the number:
[image]

Currently, the value axis looks like this and it should have an icon next to the label:

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @zeroin's answer, I found a solution. However, there seems to be a strange bug when using an axis bullet with a template. Not every bullet is hidden even though its label is hidden. Here's the relevant code, a screenshot and a [codepen](https://codepen.io/ssc-hrep3/pen/oKYOpr) to reproduce.

```
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 800;
valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
valueAxis.renderer.opposite = true;
valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.dx = 13;
valueAxis.strictMinMax = true;

var image = new am4core.Image();
image.href = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/man-user.svg";
image.width = 12;
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "middle";
image.dx = 13;
image.dy = -0.5;
image.opacity = 0.3;
valueAxis.dataItems.template.bullet = image;
```

[image]

**EDIT2:**

This bug seems to be fixed in the current release of amcharts (`4.5.14`). It works now as expected.

Comment: Thank you for noticing, we will try to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is right on time - in a version released today (4.5.9) we added bullet property to AxisDataItem. So you can add image or any other sprite to all axis labels via template or create axis range at a value you need and add bullet there, like:

```
var range = valueAxis.axisRanges.create();
range.value = 1500;
//range.label.text = "1500";

var image = new am4core.Image();
image.href = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/man-user.svg";
image.width = 15;
image.horizontalCenter = "middle";
image.verticalCenter = "middle";
image.dx = -55;
range.bullet = image;
```

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/JgXqvp

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I'm currently trying to do that, but I'm not quite sure how to add the image to all axis labels via template. I tried using `valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.dataItem.bullet` but `dataItem` is not yet defined at that point. Is the idea to retroactively add this image to the axis via event (`series.events.on('inited', () => { valueAxis.renderer.labels.each(...) }); });`)? Unfortunately, this approach did not work properly, as it sometimes (not always...) just did not add the images.

Comment: try to add it to `valueAxis.dataItems.template.bullet`

Comment: Great, thanks! But there seems to be a bug with this. See my updated question.

Comment: The bug seems to be fixed in the current release! Thanks again!